# How to convert a single dimensional object to a multi-dimensional object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

Here I made a code to convert a multi-dimensional object to a single-dimensional object ->

```
const magic = (obj, parent)=>{
  for(let key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object')
    {
      magic(obj[key], parent+"-"+key);
  }
  else{
    ans[parent + "-" + key] = obj[key];
  }
  }
}

const obj = {
  id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'Jack',
        address: {
            line1: 'westwish st',
            line2: 'washmasher',
            city: 'wallas',
            state: 'WX'
        }
    }
}

magic(obj, "obj");
```

I'm trying to make this 1D object into a Multi-D object again but running into many bugs.
Please help me out to write the function to convert this 1D object to a Multi-D object.

**Example of the converted 1D object:**

```
{
obj-id: 101 ,
obj-email: "jack@dev.com" ,
obj-personalInfo-name: "Jack" ,
obj-personalInfo-address-line1: "westwish st" ,
obj-personalInfo-address-line2: "washmasher" ,
obj-personalInfo-address-city: "wallas" ,
obj-personalInfo-address-state: "WX"
}
```

Comment: Do you what you did above, but in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can build this atop a function that adds a path such as `['personalInfo' , 'address', 'city']` and an associated value to an object, something like this:

```js
const addPath = ([p, ...ps], val, obj) => 
  ps .length == 0
    ? {...obj, [p]: val}
    : {...obj, [p]: addPath (ps, val, obj[p] || {})}
```

Then our reversed magic function is simple:

```js
const cigam = (obj) =>  // "magic" backwards
  Object .entries (obj) 
     .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => addPath (k .split ('-'), v, a), {})
```

However, I also think your `magic` function could be cleaned up a bit, especially as it's altering a variable outside its scope, `ans`.  I often write some version of `pathEntries` which could convert your original into something like

```js
[
    ['id', 101] ,
    ['email', 'jack@dev.com'],
    ['personalInfo-name', 'Jack'],
    ['personalInfo-address-line1', 'westwish st'],
    ['personalInfo-address-line2', 'washmasher'],
    ['personalInfo-address-city', 'wallas'],
    ['personalInfo-address-state', 'WX']
]
```

With that, we can write `magic` as simply as

```js
const magic = (obj) =>
  Object .fromEntries (pathEntries (obj))
```

This does not include your `parent` property, which seems superfluous to me, but if you wanted it, we would just add a bit:

```js
const magic = (obj, parent) =>
  Object .fromEntries (pathEntries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => [`${parent}-${k}`, v]))
```

Putting this all together, we can do this:

```js
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [k + (p ? '-' : '') + p, v])
      ) 
    : [['', obj]]

const magic = (obj) =>
  Object .fromEntries (pathEntries (obj))

const addPath = ([p, ...ps], val, obj) => 
  ps .length == 0
    ? {...obj, [p]: val}
    : {...obj, [p]: addPath (ps, val, obj[p] || {})}

const cigam = (obj) =>  // "magic" backwards
  Object .entries (obj) 
     .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => addPath (k .split ('-'), v, a), {})

const obj = {id: 101, email: "jack@dev.com", personalInfo: {name: "Jack", address: {line1: "westwish st", line2: "washmasher", city: "wallas", state: "WX"}}}

const enchanted = magic (obj)
console .log (enchanted)
const unenchanted = cigam (enchanted)
console .log (unenchanted)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And if you do want that `parent` property, it wouldn't change much:

```js
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [k + (p ? '-' : '') + p, v])
      ) 
    : [['', obj]]

const magic = (obj, name) =>
  Object .fromEntries (pathEntries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => [`${name}-${k}`, v]))

const addPath = ([p, ...ps], val, obj) => 
  ps .length == 0
    ? {...obj, [p]: val}
    : {...obj, [p]: addPath (ps, val, obj[p] || {})}

const cigam = (obj) =>  // "magic" backwards
  Object .entries (obj) 
     .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => addPath (k .split ('-'), v, a), {})

const obj = {id: 101, email: "jack@dev.com", personalInfo: {name: "Jack", address: {line1: "westwish st", line2: "washmasher", city: "wallas", state: "WX"}}}

const enchanted = magic (obj, 'obj')
console .log (enchanted)
const unenchanted = cigam (enchanted) ['obj']
console .log (unenchanted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this iteratively by firstly creating a result object, which will contain the keys from your input object. For each key, you can split by  `-` to get the individual keys for your object in an array. You can also pop the last key off your array of keys so you can set it to a value once you reach your final object. For each key, you can check if it exists in the current object, and if it does, update the current pointer to point to that object, otherwise, you can create a new empty object for the given key. Once you reach the last object, you can set the key you previously popped off the array onto your current object like so:

```js
const reverseMagic = (obj)=>{
  const res = {};
  for(const path in obj) {
    const keys = path.split('-');
    const last = keys.pop();
    // Walk down the properties, create them if they don't exist
    let curr = res;
    for(const key of keys) {
      curr[key] = curr[key] || {};
      curr = curr[key];
    }
    curr[last] = obj[path];
  }
  return res;
}


const obj = { "obj-id": 101 , "obj-email": "jack@dev.com" , "obj-personalInfo-name": "Jack" , "obj-personalInfo-address-line1": "westwish st" , "obj-personalInfo-address-line2": "washmasher" , "obj-personalInfo-address-city": "wallas" , "obj-personalInfo-address-state": "WX" };
console.log(reverseMagic(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I was able to do what you need using recursion:

```js
// Demo object
const x = {
    obj1: "Hello",
    obj2: {
        obj3: "hi",
        obj4: {
            obj5: "greetings",
            obj6: "goodbye"
        }
    }
}

function flatObj(obj){
    const flattenObj = {}; // New one dimensional object
    // Loop over keys
    for (const key in obj) {

        if (typeof obj[key] !== "object") {
            // If not an object, append it to flattened object
            flattenObj[key] = obj[key]; 
        } else {
            // If it is an object, flatten the object then append each key
            const temp = flatObj(obj[key]);
            for(const tempKey in temp){
                flattenObj[`${key}-${tempKey}`] = temp[tempKey];
            }
        }
    }
    // Return one dimension object
    return flattenObj;
}

flatObj(x);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  The OP can already do this.  The question was how to reverse the process, to rehydrate an object from this flattened one.